# Connectivity(Graph Theory).

Tags: graph-theory

Today, I studied in mathematics but I confuse something:

Say, $G$ is $k-$connected if $\kappa(G)\ge k$.

$\kappa(G)$ is the smallest $|S|$ such that $S\subset V(G)$ and $G-S$ is disconnected or a single (only one vertex).

For $\kappa(G)\ge k$, there is a graph such that $\kappa(G)> k$ ?

Comment: I try some graph then i get $\kappa(G) = k$

Comment: When you say single, do you mean has one vertex?

Comment: Can someone give me a example for $2-$connected has $\kappa(G)=3$

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Of course

Comment: @kimwenasa I think the word you're looking for is "singleton."

Comment: It should be clear that any $3$-connected graph is also $2$-connected and $1$-connected. In general, the definition implies that if you found a $k$-connected graph, then it is also $\ell$-connected for all $\ell\leq k$.

Comment: And also are you dealing with finite graphs, because it seems that $\kappa(G)$ could be infinity else.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Oh, I see then $C_n$ is 2-connected but 3-connected, what's about 4-connected so is ?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Thank a lot.